# Random double Generator for a new position

Tags: java, random, double

I have a code that replicates a gravitational pull towards my mouse cursor when entered in the parameters.  When the mouse is click, it creates a reverse effect pushing objects(Rectangle away from it).  I am trying to set it so when you do click and hold, when the objects hit a certain number in the x or y coordinate, it will randomly change x and y of that object.  Here is my code.  The commented area is where I tried to make x and y go random when it hits 500 parameters.

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.util.Random;
    public class Ball
{

private Color col;
private double x, y;         // location
private double vx, vy;       // velocity

public Ball(int new_x, int new_y, int new_vx, int new_vy)
{
     x = new_x; 
     y = new_y; 
     vx = new_vx; 
     vy = new_vy;
}

public Ball()
{
    Random gen = new Random();
    x = gen.nextInt(480);
    y = gen.nextInt(480);
    vx = gen.nextInt(10);
    vy = gen.nextInt(10);

    col = new Color(gen.nextInt(255),gen.nextInt(255),gen.nextInt(255));

}

void paint( Graphics h)
{
    h.setColor(col);
    h.fillRect((int)x,(int)y,20,20);  
}

void move(int currentX, int currentY, boolean isButtonPressed )
{
    double dvx, dvy, rx, ry;
    double r_mag;


    x = x + vx;
    y = y + vy;  

    //bounce
    if  (x > 480 || x < 0)
       vx = -vx;
    if (y > 480 || y < 0)
        vy = -vy;



   if ( currentX <500 && currentY <500)   // mouse is on canvas, apply "gravity" 
   {
      rx = currentX - x;
      ry = currentY - y;
      r_mag = Math.sqrt((rx*rx) + (ry*ry));

//           if ( x = 500 || y = 500)
//             Random x = new Random();
//             x.nextDouble();
//             Random y = new Random();
//             y.nextDouble();

      if (r_mag < 1)
        r_mag = 1;

      dvx = (rx / r_mag);
      dvy = (ry / r_mag);

      if (isButtonPressed)
      {
        vx = vx - dvx;   // + makes balls move to cursor.
        vy = vy - dvy;   // - makes balls move away from cursor. 
      }
      else 
      {
        vx = vx + dvx;   // + makes balls move to cursor.
        vy = vy + dvy;   // - makes balls move away from cursor.

      }
    }

    // reduce speed slowly
    vx = .99*vx;
    vy = .99*vy;
}

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

> The commented area is where I tried to make x and y go random when it hits 500 parameters.

So when `x` or `y` reaches 500, you want to randomly relocate the object?

Instead of

```
//           if ( x = 500 || y = 500)
```

this is assignment, not comparison

```
//             Random x = new Random();
```

redeclares `x`, not what you want

```
//             x.nextDouble();
```

statement without effect

```
//             Random y = new Random();
//             y.nextDouble();
```

see above

you could use `Math.random()`, as in

```
if (x == 500 || y == 500) {
    x = Math.random()*480;
    y = Math.random()*480;
}
```

(note: `Math.random()` returns a `double` in the half-open interval `[0,1)`, so you have to scale it; the scaling factor of `480` I used is a guess), or (less good, IMO) create a new `Random` instance each time you enter the `if`.

But,

1. `x`, `y`, and the velocities `vx` and `vy` are `doubles`, so it is very unlikely that the movements let `x` or `y` become exactly `500`, so you should probably test for `>=` rather than `==` in the condition.
2. In the code, you flip the velocity when either coordinate passes 480, so getting to 500 or farther is difficult and can only be achieved by judicious acceleration using the mouse, so a smaller threshold may be wanted.

Comment: Okay.  I am understanding, but it is still not accepting the x = gen.nextDouble()*480;  It says the gen is not a recognized variable.

Comment: Oh, oops, it's local to the constructor. Missed that, sorry. You can a) make it an instance variable, b) create a new `Random` instance, c) use `Math.random()`. IMO, c) is the best option, and you might also use `Math.random()` in the constructor.

Comment: if (currentX == 5 || currentY == 5 ) {
              currentY = Math.random()*480;
               currentX = Math.random()*480; }  but it doesnt work

Comment: As I wrote, getting to _exactly_ some specified value is very unlikely, so check `>= someValue`. And aren't `currentX` and `currentY` the mouse coordinates? I thought you wanted to relocate the ball when it reaches some position, so you'd have to use its `x` and `y` coordinates - maybe you have to communicate the new position explicitly to the graphic object responsible for drawing.